# When is a word processor better than LaTeX?

Tags: msword

I've read about the benefits of LaTeX for creating high-quality typography in documents, but I'm wondering in what situations a word processor (e.g., Word) is better.

For instance, are reports with multiple graphics better suited to something like Word? And what about resumes?

Comment: Perhaps a question that would receive much more affirmative answers in a MS Word site.

Comment: In my needs (writing things for the university) I don't find a situation where I need Word. By the way, it's not (in my case) the *high-quality typography* which attracts me, but the possibility to write what I want rather than seen it (I absolutely prefer to tell him that the font size is 19 rather than seen it the actual size). Plus the ability to create new commands which do what I want.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and would probably attract some good answers. Just because you like a certain tool, that doesn't mean it's the right tool for all jobs.

Comment: This is an interesting question, especially here in this forum. Under which circumstances do hardcore TeXies (ok, this is a German expression, but you understand it?!) prefer using a word processor?

Comment: Documents with 1-5 pages, with just text and one title in the beginning. Stuff that's not going to be put online or sent to anyone, talks for example. No figures, no tables etc. Also when you need collaboration but don't need the document to look good, Google Docs is better.

Comment: for very short documents, where typography is less important.  for me, the rule is <1 page.  the latex overhead in the .tex file itself, plus the overhead in the file system with multiple created files, make latex painful compared to a word processor.